What are the main sources of magnetic fields?
Is the generation of magnetic fields mainly due to certain spins of particles and the movement of electric charges?
I mean fundamentally what are the sources. I recognize in aggregate, whatever generates magnetic fields will then result in bar magnets, planetary magnetic fields, etc. I'm asking about the fundamental physical origins of it. Not just "what in general can make magnetic fields?"
Also, if spin and moving charges are the primary sources, why are there two separate source? Electric fields come from charge, which is one source. Why would magnetic have two different causes?
EDIT:
I read this paragraph from Griffiths

If you ask the average person what "magnetism" is, you will probably be told about refrigerator decorations, compass needles, and the North Pole-none of which has any obvious connection with moving charges or current-carrying wires. Yet all magnetic phenomena are due to electric charges in motion, and in fact, if you could examine a piece of magnetic material on an atomic scale you would
find tiny currents: electrons orbiting around nuclei and spinning about their axes.
For macroscopic purposes, these current loops are so small that we may treat them
as magnetic dipoles. Ordinarily, they cancel each other out because of the random
orientation of the atoms. But when a magnetic field is applied, a net alignment of
these magnetic dipoles occurs, and the medium becomes magnetically polarized,
or magnetized.

Is part of the reason that magnetic fields are produced by both translational and rotational motion of charges? Therefore, a charge pursuing some path would induce a magnetic field (e.g. a wire) but so would a charge spinning on its axis? But if that's true, why wouldn't there be magnetic fields at rest and why would Coulomb's law still apply?

The old answer below misses the mark. I am tryin again.
New Answer
Classically speaking, electric fields are generated by electric charges and changing magnetic fields. Magnetic fields are generated by magnetic charges and changing electric fields. But there are no magnetic charges so magnetic fields are only generated by changing electric fields.
The Biot-Savart law which says moving charges create magnetic fields can be derived from Ampere's law which says that changing electric fields create charges.
The question then is: Why are magnetic fields additionally sourced by quantum fields with intrinsic spin? The answer, from me, is still "I don't know".
Old Answer
Yes, the two fundamental sources of magnetic fields are moving charges and particle intrinsic spin. It’s a good question why magnetic fields have two sources whereas electric fields have one. This is why you might think intrinsic spin is due to small charged particles moving or rotating, but from what we can tell it is not.
I don’t know why this is the case, maybe something to do with relativity. Curious to hear what others say.

Not an expert but knowledgeable enough to make an observation.  If intrinsic particle spin creates a field, then I would imagine that a larger aggregate of charged particles would also produce the spinning effect.  In other words, maybe the two sources you discuss are essentially macroscopic and microscopic versions of the same thing?

@MarianoG I think intrinsic spin and is definitelly different than extrinsic angular momentum. I think this is most strikingly demonstrated by the factor of 2 difference in the Lande G factor for intrinsic electron spin angular momentum compared to electron orbital angular momentum.
